# RSS feed for TYPO3 Blog Extension

Tags: rss, typo3, blogs

I want to create a RSS feed for the TYPO3 Blog extension.

The TypoScript of the extensions provides following code:

```
blog_rss_posts = PAGE
blog_rss_posts {
    typeNum = 201
    10 < tt_content.list.20.blog_posts

    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        no_cache = 1
        additionalHeaders {
            10 {
                header = Content-type: application/xml
            }
        }
        xhtml_cleaning = 1
        admPanel = 0
    }
}
```

But when Im calling the feed via http://localhost/blog/?type=201
I only got the warning

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

And the Html-Code of the articles. Did I missed something?
I want it in the right XML-format

Comment: Which extension exactly? There a multiple blog extensions for TYPO3.

Comment: It just calls blog
https://packagist.org/packages/t3g/blog

Answer (score 0):

The browser has of course no CSS for the XML provided by the RSS feed. To check whether e.g. the content field has html code, you should use the source code view of your browser. In Chrome thats Ctrl+U (Windows) or Cmd-Opt-U (Mac).

Comment: I just want a simple XML-Output. No HTML and no CSS 
Just infos about the title, description, image and so on

Comment: The warning is something your browser does. It's not included in the XML output from your server. Check the source code, that's the raw xml output! Or use any feed validator like https://validator.w3.org/feed/ to validate your feed.

Comment: He shows me this:
https://i.imgur.com/nMgA261.png

With all HTML-Tags.  Is there a way to remove them, so that only the values are visible?

Comment: The stuff on your screenshot is still not the raw output from the server! You used the inspect code from the context menu, correct? Use the shortcut I've mentioned above!

Comment: You are right. The server gives me pure HTML with  cmd-U

Comment: Do I need an own template for my XML-structure?

Comment: Have a look at the Templates and Partials folders in Resources/Private/

Comment: Now I changed my TS to

    blog_rss_posts = PAGE
    blog_rss_posts {
       typeNum = 202
        config {
         disableAllHeaderCode = 1
         additionalHeaders = Content-type:text/xml;charset=utf-8
         xhtml_cleaning = none
         admPanel = 0
    }

     10 = TEMPLATE
     10.template = FILE
     10.template.file = EXT:blog/Resources/Private/Layouts/Default.rss

    }

the XML file loads correct, but I have no clue how I can add the values from tt_content.list.20.blog_posts

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that deep into EXT:blog. I'd suggest that you create a new Stackoverflow question and then post the link to the Slack Channel #t3g-ext-blog (https://typo3.slack.com/messages/C1XLMLRM1). If you don't have a slack account, you can get one here: https://my.typo3.org/index.php?id=35